# Add symfony console to PhpStorm

Tags: php, symfony, console, phpstorm

I'm trying to add the symfony2 console to phpStorm (v10.0.3) but I'm getting an error like this:

[image]

But it's working in the console

[image]

Symfony console is correct and php path is too, because I can create bundle like "php app\console generate:bundle"

Anyone know why PhpStorm is returning error?

Comment: Try newer PhpStorm version: latest stable is 2016.1.2 and EAP is 2016.2

Comment: I update phpStorm to newest version 10.0.4 and still return error

Comment: Can you see the difference between **10.0.4** and **2016.1.2** ??

Comment: Excellence .. it's work fine. Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the parameters properly.

1. Path to Symfony -> path to 'app/console'
2. Path to PHP executable -> click dropdown and select the proper PHP executable location (full path to the executable PHP - in your case php.exe). If you are not sure then type `where php.exe` to get the exact location of the exe file.
3. Symfony component version -> Select your Symfony version (version 2.x or 3.x)

[image: PhpStorm Command Line Tool setup]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello. 1 nad 2 don't help. 3rd pint I don't know where is it. Where can i change symfony version.

Comment: I am using PhpStorm in Mac so I really don't have any idea about the differences to Windows. But after looking your screenshots a bit deeply, I want to know something more from you.

1. Why are you using -V after the console command. It just gives you the version of Symfony
2. Did you try to use the full path of php instead of just typing php.exe?
3. Are you running WAMP? Make sure that the server is running before you start to do the settings, because the IDE tries to check if everything is in proper order.

I cannot post an image in this reply so I am editing my original answer.

Comment: I fix this problem for update from 10.0.4 to 2016.1.2 PHPstorm and it's show me new options like you have. However thanks form help.